# Bootstrap Datepicker is Not Loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-datepicker

Actually, I am building a new website with Bootstrap3 and I'm not able to have my field enabled with DatePicker... I still don't know what I am doing wrong...

http://cpan-01.kpc-solutions.net/~clublaboom/guestlist.html

The "Date..." Field should show the datepicker by clicking on it but it isn't working.

Can somebody help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: can you check you console for your any errors also if possible could you create a jsfiddle and replicate your issue there, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Put the call to bootstrap-datepicker.js under the call of jQuery

Comment: it does not work while clickin in the field, but for some reason it works while clicking on the down arrow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost all web sites load jquery on header even check stackoverflow.com 
 if you see your console there is errors like  `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`
because `$` is not available at that place of `$(document).ready` because code execution take place up to down in browser and $ define when this line

```
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

execute, so you can put  `jquery` load on header so you can use it anywhere on page or write jquery code after where you include it

write this piece of code  after include jquery will also solve your problem

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            // When the document is ready
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#example1').datepicker({
                    format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
                });  

            });
        </script>
```

because after  where you include `jquery` you can use $ as you use in `$(document).ready` function

Comment: Or this script can be added directly underneath the section where the scripts are loaded - rather than loading the scripts at the top of the document.